# QueryException - query non selective

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

I recently deployed a trigger to production. Inside it was the following query:

```
SELECT Id,
    (SELECT Business_Unit__c, Department__c, Role__c FROM Account_Roles__r WHERE Role__c IN :roles AND Business_Unit__c IN :businessUnits ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC NULLS FIRST )
FROM Account
WHERE Id IN :accIds
    AND Id IN (SELECT Account__c FROM SKY_Account_Role__c)
ORDER BY Name ASC NULLS FIRST
```

Unfortunately the trigger started to fail on production with `QueryException: Non-selective query` error. I am having hard time debugging it since the issue occurs neither on sandbox environment nor in Execute Anonymous in production.

So my question is: **which part may be causing that Exception?** After some investigation and discussion I'm leaning towards adding filter on semi-join:

```
    SELECT Id,
    (SELECT Business_Unit__c, Department__c, Role__c FROM Account_Roles__r WHERE Role__c IN :roles AND Business_Unit__c IN :businessUnits ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC NULLS FIRST )
FROM Account
WHERE Id IN :accIds
    AND Id IN (SELECT Account__c FROM SKY_Account_Role__c WHERE Id IN :accIds)
ORDER BY Name ASC NULLS FIRST
```

Comment: If you haven't already, take a look to see if the query plan tool https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000199003&type=1 offers anything helpful in your sandbox.

Comment: Unfortunately it's completely useless in this scenario, it just says: 'This query plan doesn't have any notes.'

Comment: Pity. For what it is worth, your suggested solution would be the first thing I would try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your analysis is correct. How many records are there in `SKY_Account_Role__c`? This query will be problematic if there are more than 200,000 `SKY_Account_Role__c` records:

```
SELECT Account__c FROM SKY_Account_Role__c
```

Have you tried your own suggestion of filtering that sub-query yet? You probably want it like this (rather than the one in your question):

```
SELECT Account__c FROM SKY_Account_Role__c WHERE Account__c IN :accIds
```

Comment: Yes, the count is over 200,000. I wasn't 100% sure if semi-joins can also cause this exception since they aren't calculated into limit of SOQL rows. I see that a lot of people agree with that solution so I will push that to production and check what happens. Thanks!